# SFDX retrieve source from org doesn't retrieve new flow

Tags: salesforcedx, visual-workflow

I can retrieve source, but I don't see the updated files. I doubt existing files are updated too. Some posts I read suggests to deploy it to make a connection before retrieving, but wouldn't that override my code and flow in the org?

package.xml

```xml
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>Flow</name>
</types>
```

Comment: what exactly are you doing to retrieve? A command in the terminal (in that case, which one)? Are you right clicking within VS Code on the folder/file (`retrieve source from org`) or on the package.xml (`retrieve source from manifest`)

Comment: @KrisGoncalves right clicking on folder in VS Code

Comment: @KrisGoncalves Right clicking on xml works. Solved thanks.